# Playframework + Flash policy file

Tags: flash, playframework-2.0, netty

I know that playframework 2 relies on netty and that there are several project on github that provide this functionality for netty, for example: https://github.com/cgbystrom/netty-tools

But I have no idea where to implement this, I have never developed with netty before, can anyone provide some pointers on how I can allow play framework provide flash policy file?

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not deal with play framework. But to see netty code which serves a flash policy file, take look at this [netty based java game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) which uses flash policy server. The relevant class is org.menacheri.jetserver.server.netty.FlashPolicyServer. It also provides and [as3](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/tree/master/jetclient-as3) based client.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I have looked at the code, its a really good reference to learn from.  I know that this is a very simple question, Im still at the basics, but currently Play framework already is using netty, they have a netty server configured. From the play framework perspective, whats the best way to add this "flash file policy" into my project?  Is there a general practice, patter?

Comment: Not experienced with play framework so cant help on that. Generally, you have a file with your rules setup and then you serve it using the handler, it should be as easy or more easier with play i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at a lot of different options to modify netty, but at the end, ended up running a seperate server based on: github.com/waywardmonkeys/netty-flash-crossdomain-policy-server

It all seems to work not.

But for the future, if anyone know how I can allow playframework to itself provide the policy file on port 843, that would be greatly appreciated.